# Reduce returning string and not number

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The objective is to obtain a sum of the fields with the same month, obtaining a final result, inflictably the code I managed to do returns a string and I don't know why. how i make this work?
I've already tried to put number (acc.Fuel) but the result is always the same, I'm trying to get that result to be able to make a graph, so the final result really has to be like this in number, I thank everyone who might miss a little time to help and I apologize in advance as I am a junior in this development phase.

the object final shoud be like this :

```js
  {
    name: 'Fuel',
    data: [30, 40, 45, 50, 49, 60, 70]
  },
```

what i have:

json data:

```js
[
    {
        "Data": "01/01/2009 00:00:00",
        "Ilha": "1",
        "Fuel": "43575070.000",
        "Diesel": "5963754.000",
        "TermFuel": "NULL",
        "Hidrica": "2084379.000",
        "Geotermica": "14775549.410",
        "Eolica": "3771650.000",
        "Biogas": "2502.000",
        "Aux": "1634838.600"
    },
    {
        "Data": "01/02/2009 00:00:00",
        "Ilha": "1",
        "Fuel": "NULL",
        "Diesel": "1509490.000",
        "TermFuel": "NULL",
        "Hidrica": "NULL",
        "Geotermica": "NULL",
        "Eolica": "296600.000",
        "Biogas": "NULL",
        "Aux": "56909.000"
    },
    {
        "Data": "01/03/2009 00:00:00",
        "Ilha": "1",
        "Fuel": "21061010.000",
        "Diesel": "6887.000",
        "TermFuel": "NULL",
        "Hidrica": "1534690.000",
        "Geotermica": "14775549.410",
        "Eolica": "NULL",
        "Biogas": "2502.000",
        "Aux": "478623.000"
    }
]
```

```js
const newIlha = DataOptions.map((ilha) => ({
    ...ilha,
    teste: Number(ilha.Fuel),
    mes: ilha.Data.split('/')[0],
    dia: ilha.Data.split('/')[1],
    ano: ilha.Data.split('/')[2].split(' ')[0]
  }))
const series = newIlha.reduce(
    (acc, cur) => [
      {
        name: 'Fuel',
        data: MesesOptions.map((month) => [
          acc.find((x) => x.name === 'Fuel').data[0] +
            (cur.mes === month.value
              ? month.value === 'NULL'
                ? 0
                : cur.teste
              : 0)
        ])
      }
    ],
    [
      { name: 'Fuel', data: [0] },
      { name: 'Diesel', data: [0] },
      { name: 'TermFuel', data: [0] },
      { name: 'Hidrica', data: [0] },
      { name: 'Geotermica', data: [0] },
      { name: 'Eolica', data: [0] },
      { name: 'Biogas', data: [0] },
      { name: 'Aux', data: [0] }
    ]
  )
```

the results i'm getting:

```js
0:
data: Array(12)
0: ["59637541509490688784733010255902135470363680028222…0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"]
1: ["59637541509490688784733010255902135470363680028222…0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"]
2: ["59637541509490688784733010255902135470363680028222…0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"]
3: ["59637541509490688784733010255902135470363680028222…0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"]
4: ["59637541509490688784733010255902135470363680028222…0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"]
5: ["59637541509490688784733010255902135470363680028222…0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"]
6: ["59637541509490688784733010255902135470363680028222…0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"]
7: ["59637541509490688784733010255902135470363680028222…0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"]
8: ["59637541509490688784733010255902135470363680028222…0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"]
9: ["59637541509490688784733010255902135470363680028222…0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"]
10: ["59637541509490688784733010255902135470363680028222…0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"]
11: ["59637541509490688784733010255902135470363680028222…0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000NaN"]
length: 12
__proto__: Array(0)
name: "Fuel"
__proto__: Object
```

working exemple [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-taussig-lqpeb)

Comment: Questions should be self-contained. Future visitors shouldn't need to visit off-site link to understand the question or answers. Please [edit] your post to include a [mcve].

Comment: Add the code you use to reduce the values. You have only added the object. Also, what string do you get as the result of the reduce function?

Comment: What is the question here? You are showing your desired result but not what would be the input

Comment: Sorry, i just rebuild the question, hope this is ok now,  really sorry

Comment: Please share what is newIlha?

Comment: @TusharShahi i have added json data and newilha map

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) on `input` to create the desired result.

We start by creating a map of the data, keyed by month, e.g. { '01': {}, '02': {} }. We can then add up the valid totals using parseFloat and .reduce again.

I've added a datapoint from the next month to show the totals by month.

And to create a map of results by month:

```js
let input = [
    {
        "Data": "01/01/2009 00:00:00",
        "Ilha": "1",
        "Fuel": "43575070.000",
        "Diesel": "5963754.000",
        "TermFuel": "NULL",
        "Hidrica": "2084379.000",
        "Geotermica": "14775549.410",
        "Eolica": "3771650.000",
        "Biogas": "2502.000",
        "Aux": "1634838.600"
    },
    {
        "Data": "01/02/2009 00:00:00",
        "Ilha": "1",
        "Fuel": "NULL",
        "Diesel": "1509490.000",
        "TermFuel": "NULL",
        "Hidrica": "NULL",
        "Geotermica": "NULL",
        "Eolica": "296600.000",
        "Biogas": "NULL",
        "Aux": "56909.000"
    },
    {
        "Data": "01/03/2009 00:00:00",
        "Ilha": "1",
        "Fuel": "21061010.000",
        "Diesel": "6887.000",
        "TermFuel": "NULL",
        "Hidrica": "1534690.000",
        "Geotermica": "14775549.410",
        "Eolica": "NULL",
        "Biogas": "2502.000",
        "Aux": "478623.000"
    },
    
    {
        "Data": "02/01/2009 00:00:00",
        "Ilha": "1",
        "Fuel": "21061010.000",
        "Diesel": "6887.000",
        "TermFuel": "NULL",
        "Hidrica": "1534690.000",
        "Geotermica": "14775549.410",
        "Eolica": "NULL",
        "Biogas": "2502.000",
        "Aux": "478623.000"
    }
];

    
function getResultsByMonth(input, properties) {
    let result = input.reduce((acc, cur) => {
        const key = cur.Data.split('/')[0];
        if (!acc[key]) acc[key] = { };
        for(let property of properties) {
            if (!acc[key][property]) acc[key][property] = { name: property, data: [] };
            const val = parseFloat(cur[property]);
            // Filter out falsey values other than 0.
            if (val || val === 0) acc[key][property].data.push(val);
        }
        return acc;
    }, {});
    return Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(result).map(([k,v]) => [k, Object.values(v)]));
}
    

console.log("getResultsByMonth:", getResultsByMonth(input, ['Fuel', 'Diesel']));
```

Comment: that works nice thanks for that, shoud i make a map from months to output the results?

Comment: You could, I'll add an example!

Comment: ok nicely done, can you tell me why my reduce was returning string? just to know

Comment: I think it's that line: acc.find((x) => x.name === 'Fuel').data[0] + ... this is converting back teste: Number(ilha.Fuel) from a number to a string.

Comment: ok thans for the help, i was just looking, to add more then 1 property shoud be included as a new map too? for exemple: const property = ['Fuel', 'Diesel'] then include that as map?

Comment: Good but i have one small suggestion. instead let use const.

Comment: @TerryLennox , i understand you update but i was asking somting like:  0: {name:"Fuel", data: Array(12) }
1: : {name:"Diesel", data: Array(12) } like if the table head was the property

Comment: I would you like to help me to put the value of the 12 arrays inside each property for example {name: 'fuel', data:[0.1.2.3.4.5]}

Comment: I've updated again, not sure if this is exactly what you want, but it's probably closer!

Comment: yes it is really close, really tanks for you help, you can se the expected result here : https://prnt.sc/17a85z7

Comment: Is that closer? Or am I going in the wrong direction? :-) Thanks!

Comment: yes its closer, but the "name": "Diesel", shoud be outside

Comment: So, maybe something like: { 01: [{ name: 'Fuel', data: [1,2,3] }, { name: 'Diesel', data: [3,4,5] } ] }?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234299/discussion-between-noobdev-gbl-and-terry-lennox).

Comment: @TerryLennox yes you got that, i made my corrections base on your exemple, now working fine, rellay tanks for the help